# Executing multiple Firestore and Firebase queries for FlatLists

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

New to Firebase and RN, I am trying to populate a FlatList data source with text and an image for each item.

Looking to perform a Firestore get() query and run another Firestore get() query and storage ref on the result of the original query snapshot.

Should I nest these calls or have external functions called.

Here's what I've tried so far ...

```
var limit = 10;
var firedb = firebase.firestore();
var firestorage = firebase.storage();
var posts = firedb.collection('posts');
var postsArr = [];
var nextToPullList = [];
var counter = 0;

posts.where('post_user.user_uid', '==', currentUser.uid).orderBy('post_order', 'desc').limit(limit).get()
.then( async snapshot => {
    if (!snapshot.empty) {
        snapshot.forEach( doc => {
            var childData = doc.data();

            postsArr.push(childData);
            nextToPullList.push(childData.post_order);
        });
        postsArr.forEach( async element => {

            await firestorage.ref(element.post_image_name).getDownloadURL()
            .then( (url) => {
                element.image_uri = {uri: url};
                counter++;
            });
            if (counter === limit){
                var dataSource = this.state.dataSource.concat(postsArr);
                var nextToPull = nextToPullList[nextToPullList.length - 1];
                this.setState({
                    dataSource: dataSource,
                    nextToPull: nextToPull,
                });
            }
        });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Either should be fine - use the structure that is most maintainable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by using the structure that was the most maintainable